# Href download file not found

Tags: html, href

I am trying to build a website with a downloadable file using `href`. When I try to click on the link it takes me to a new page saying file not found here. The file path is:

> /home/myname/linktoserver/texturepack/blob.zip

Here is the code that I am attempting to use.

```
<a href="/linktoserver/texturepack/blob.zip" download="blob">
  <center>blob</center>
</a>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML file located? Do you have a `www` or `public_html` folder? Your home directory is not accessible from the web, for good reason.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: it is located in www

Comment: Try this - `href="../linktoserver/texturepack/blob.zip"`

Comment: I tried it still says file not found

Answer (score 1):

Without asking lots of questions, the fastest way is this:

put the blob.zip in the same folder as your index.html file.

then use

```
<a href="blob.zip" download="blob">
  <center>blob</center>
</a>
```

Comment: Hi I tried you suggestion and it still says fill not found when I click on the link